# Prevent Designer from adding namespace to custom control constructor

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have created a usercontrol ´MyButton´ in the namespace ´MyControls´

```vb
Namespace MyControls

   <ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.ToolStrip)>
   Public Class MyButton
       Inherits ToolStripButton
       ' Controls staff
   End Class

End Namespace
```

Using designer my control was added to the form. And everything works ok. But after making some changes in the designer I got error

> `Type 'MyProject.MyControls.MyButton' is not defined.`

Error's codeline is: `Me.ButtonClose = New MyProject.MyControls.MyButton()`

So problem is because In the project I have a module with same name as project name - `MyProject` and generated code `New MyProject.MyControls.MyButton()` trying to find type of MyButton in that module.

Changing code of designer manually (adding `Global` keyword or removing `MyProject` prefix) will not work, because after next change in designer, code will be re-generated and errors will comeback.

In other hand designer not added `MyProject` namespace in the definition of the control
`Friend WithEvents ButtonClose As MyControls.MyButton`

Question: Is it possible to prevent designer adding `MyProject` namespace or removing `Global`? Because I cannot change a name of the module - it is used in other projects already

Comment: In VB14, this may [work better](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/571884) (see "Smart Name Resolution") but I'm not aware of anything you can do now short of what you've said you don't want to do - rename the module - or rename the project. Having multiple "things" with the same name will tend to keep causing issues.

Comment: Do you have a root namespace setup in your projects properties?  You could try clearing that, but it may cause other namespace conflicts elsewhere.

Comment: Definition of module is without root namespace

Comment: The whole serializing to code can be controlled (by providing a custom codedom serializer), but it's definitely a lot of pain, and you should avoid this by all means unless you **really** need it. If I was you, instead of going that route, I'd definitely rename the module and try not to have colliding names at all.